# Installing SSL on Apache - Syntax Error in openssl.cnf

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, webserver, httpd.conf

I'm trying to learn how to get ssl up and running on an apache 2.4 webserver (Windows Server 2012). I had the web server and PHP up and running perfectly fine without SSL.

- I Generated my cert and key and placed them in C:\Apache24\conf
- I Modified httpd.conf in the following way:

> ```
> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
> Include C:/Apache24/conf/openssl.cnf
> ```

- I modified c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf in the following way:

> `SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server.crt"
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server.key"
>   DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"`

- Added the following System Environment Variable

> `Variable Name: OPENSSL_CONF
>   Variable Value: C:\Apache24\conf\openssl.cnf`

I've hit a point where apache will not start due to the following error.

running httpd -t in powershell gives the result:

```
: Syntax error on line 8 of C:/Apache24/conf/openssl.cnf:
Invalid command 'HOME', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The following are lines 6 through 9 of openssl.cnf ( I have not modified this file. )

```
# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
```

**Any help is appreciated.
Thanks !**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to include a third party config file inside httpd configuration, which will never yield a good result because Apache httpd will never recognize what's in there. **Remove that include**.

If you want to add system variables you can use PassEnv directive from mod_env module.

To get SSL up and running all you need is a SSL virtualhost like this:

In your server config something like:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 443
        LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
        SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
        SSLCompression          off
        SSLSessionTickets       off
        SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 2048 # perhaps this need to be adapted for windows
        SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 2048 # same with this
        SSLSessionCache shmcb:/path/to/logs/ssl_gcache_data(512000)
</IfModule>
```

And the Virtualhost:

```
<Virtualhost *:443>
ServerName myssllvh.example.com
DocumentRoot /filesystem/path/to/docroot
CustomLog /path/to/logs/mysslvh.log combined
ErrorLog /path/to/logs/mysslvh-error.log

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certs/mysslvh.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/certs/mysslvh.key

# Other stuff here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks !
The Apache server will start now.

i changed the /dev/urandom path to C:/Temp/rand....

Hovever, when i try to visit the site in firefox i get "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"